# How to hide the border and background color of the drop-down arrow of a HTML <select> element?

Tags: css, windows, firefox, firefox4

I found that in the center of [Mozilla home page](http://www.mozilla.org/), there is a <select> element (drop-down list) whose arrow has no border and background color. While on [facebook sign-up page](http://www.facebook.com/), the drop-down arrow has the windows standard border and background color. I am wondering what makes this difference? I tried to set `border` to `none` in CSS, but it only hides the border around the whole <select> element, the arrow still has border. I am using Firefox 4 on Windows.

See attached screenshot. The upper half shows the drop-down list on Facebook, while the lower half shows the drop-down list on Mozilla.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I'm being stupid, but I can't see what you're talking about.

Comment: @lonesomeday Its the country field in the newsletter form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `border` css property of the `select` element isn't overridden, then it's rendered as native as possible (the mozilla's case). When, on the other hand, the border property is specified, browser tries to render `select` with a border and sacrifices some native look of it (facebook's case).

Or, maybe, it tries to render the native combobox without border and then draws border around it. Anyhow, when the border is specified, combobox needs to be drawn in different ways windows-wise or browser-wise.

And FYI, I've got the classic theme in win7 and mozilla's `select` button looks like any other classic windows button: gray and 3D:

[image: select elemnt on mozilla site with the classic windows theme]

Comment: Found two things: 1. putting `border: none` in CSS actually makes border arrow the arrow. 2. the arrow is non-style-able.

Comment: Yeah, I've also found that once the combo isn't native (arrow button isn't transparent), you can't make it native again with css overrides.

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is not a select, but an input field with another input field of type image right next to it.  The image input acts as a submit button for a form.  Their html for it is as follows:

```
<input id="q" type="search" placeholder="Search" name="q">
<input id="quick-search-btn" type="image" alt="Search" src="/images/template/search-submit.png">
```

By the way, if you are running firefox, I would recommend getting the firebug add-on.  Then you can right click on any element and inspect it.

Comment: I'm talking about the drop-down list in the center of Mozilla.org, not the search box. I've edited the question to make it more clear. Sorry for the confusion.